# Why can't most defaulted operators have a placeholder return type, i.e. auto?

Tags: c++, language-design, return-type-deduction, defaulted-functions, c++26

C++20 has made it possible to default comparison operators, including the three-way comparison like this. `<=>` can have a deduced return type, but other operators can't:

```cpp
struct S {
    friend auto operator<=>(const S&, const S&) = default; // OK
    friend auto operator==(const S&, const S&) = default;  // error, return type must be bool
    auto& operator=(const S&) = default;                   // error, return type must be S&
};
```

Is there any reason why this restriction exists? It feels arbitrary.
The only return type that `auto` can reasonably deduce to for `operator==` is `bool`.

---

<sub>Note: This is a wiki-style Q&A and its main goal is to raise awareness for restrictive language design and a [c++26](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b26) proposal which aims to solve it.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The restriction is purely historical and there is a good chance that it's going to be lifted in C++26, assuming [P2952R0 `auto& operator=(X&&) = default`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2952r0.html) gets accepted into the standard.

From the proposal:

> ```cpp
> auto& operator=(const MyClass& rhs) { i = rhs.i; return *this; } // well-formed
> auto& operator=(const MyClass& rhs) = default; // ill-formed, must say 'MyClass&'
>
> auto operator==(const MyClass& rhs) const { return i == rhs.i; } // well-formed
> auto operator==(const MyClass& rhs) const = default; // ill-formed, must say 'bool'
> ```
>
> The ill-formedness of these declarations comes from overly restrictive wording in the standard, such as [[class.eq]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.eq#1.sentence-1) specifically requiring that a defaulted equality operator must have a declared return type of `bool`, instead of simply specifying that its return type must be `bool`. We believe each of the examples above has an intuitively clear meaning: the placeholder return type correctly matches the type which the defaulted body will actually return. We propose to loosen the current restrictions and permit these declarations to be well-formed.

In essence, the proposal would make deduced return types valid in those cases where a specific return type is expected. It would not alter the set of valid return types.

#### Implementation challenges and edge cases

It's worth noting that there is some compiler divergence when it comes to the set of valid return types. [For example](https://godbolt.org/z/h58oWG6j1):

```cpp
// only clang rejects this, other compilers allow it
friend bool operator==(const C, const C) = default;
```

However, such divergence shouldn't stand in the way of the proposal because it proposes the "canonical" return type:

> A defaulted secondary comparison operator function shall have the return type `bool`. If its declared return type contains a placeholder type, its return type is deduced as if from `return true;`.

Comment: That "edge case" isn't about return types (that function is very much returning `bool`), it's about parameter types - cause the parameters need to be either both `C` or both `C const&` (not both `C const`). I'm not sure why other implementations allow it, since either add the `&`s (to avoid copying) or drop the `const`s (since they're pointless?)